# How do I access multiple AngularFire2 observable object items

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, firebase, angularfire2

In my Ionic2 app, I am trying to access multiple items in a Firebase database via a FirebaseObjectObservable as provided by AngularFire2

My Firebase Database is

```
"users": {
  "KTBF99RXFR": {
    "name": "Ada Lovelace",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "profileimageurl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/xxx"
  }
}
```

My Observable Object is created here

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.auth.subscribe((data) => {
    if (data) {
      this.userProfile = this.af.database.object('/users/' + data.uid);
    }
  })
 }
```

Problem is I am not able to get multiple items of the object displaying in my app

```
<ion-content class="profile" >
  <h2>Name: {{ (userProfile | async)?.name }}</h2>
  <h2>URL: {{ (userProfile | async)?.profileimageurl }}</h2>
</ion-content>
```

Only the last item in the list is displayed in the app.

How do I return multiple async items of an Observable Object?

Comment: i have this exact pattern in my code and it works fine, will need to see more to see what is going on here

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Your confirmation that the code I shared was not the error led me to the error. I was not checking if I was already authenticated on app load and was logging in a second time which caused the issue.